# Line break between the number and the exponent

Tags: line-breaking, siunitx

In the Latex source I have the following text

```
$q_\text{v} = \SI{2.26e6}{\J\per\kg}$
```

and the line break happens right between the number and the exponent as

```
... qv = 2.26 ×
106 J/kg...
```

Is there any way to prevent such events?  Reading the manual, I found `allow-quantity-breaks` option, but I never used it and it is not directly related to this problem.

Comment: You could do `\sisetup{exponent-product=\times\nobreak}` but that will lead to an even worse linebreak in my test file (after the `=`).

Comment: Since version 3 of `siunitx`, the recommended command for this is `\qty` instead of `\SI` (see manual section "Upgrading from version 2").

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Why is break after the `=` worse?  To me the situation when a single number is broken into parts seems to be the worst possible case.

Comment: Unrelated never use `\text{v}` to mean upright v. That is not what `\text` does, here use `\mathrm{v}`. Additionally it is shear luck that `q_\text{v}` works, so don't count on it always use braces (`q_{...}`)

Comment: @daleif Thanks for pointing to this issue, but I am still unsure whether I should change.  According to ISO 80000, symbols are always italic and text is always upright.  In `q_\text{v}`, `v` is actually abbreviation of text vaporization, hence text and upright.  On the other hand in `q_m`, `m` is mass, hence symbol and italic.  Or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: But the `\text` will adapt to surrounding text (so maybe italic if you used inside a theorem, if the theorem text is in italic), while `\mathrm` will always set it upright. In addition to the `\nobreak` suggestion, you can consider to insert a slightly larger penalty. By default you get `700` after the times symbol. 10000 will make sure you do not get a break, so by playing a bit, you might find some intermediate value that fits your needs. If you can change `\binoppenalty` locally, that might be a better option.

Comment: Try `\textit{test $q_{\text{foo}}$}` the result may surprise you. A good syntax does not depend on context thus `\text` is not a good choice for something that needs to be upright. (there are many users who does not realise this)

Comment: @Pygmalion In my test file with random text it used very long interword spaces. This will be dependent on the actual text and how the other lines will break then. Feel free to use it if you get good results. It should be usable on a case-by-case basis `\qty[exponent-product=\times\nobreak]{…}{…}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel OK thanks.  Actually, in my 200 pages document I have a few dozen breaks after `=` and just one after `×`.  And I absolutely prefer breaks after `=`, so I will make your option global.

Comment: @daleif I understand your point. This never happened to me before, because I think that putting formula within italic text is stylistically inappropriate.  And use italic text as little as possible, only when absolutely necessary.

Comment: It is very common to have defintions or theorems in italic.

Comment: @daleif After reading ISO 80000, I have doubts about the use of `\textrm`. As shown in the example there, subscriptions should use the same font as the body text, upright of course. So if the body text is sans serif, the subscript should also be sans serif. So it seems that `\textup` and not `\textrm` is the right solution!