# Proper way to include text in formulas

Tags: typography

According to ISO 80000, physical symbols should be written in italics and everything else in normal type. So I use for example

```
$q_{m,\text{ve}}$
```

to describe the mass flow due to ventilation.  The `m` is in italics because it is a physical symbol representing mass, and `ve` is in normal type, because it is an abbreviation of ventilation.

However, it has been suggested to me (see comments to [Line break between the number and the exponent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/688561/line-break-between-the-number-and-the-exponent)) that I should use `\mathrm` instead of `\text` in these cases. This is because if I insert a formula in italicised text, `ve` will be italic too. I did some research and `\mathrm` is said to not have a proper letter spacing, so it is not really a good solution.

So another possible solution would be to define a special function for **every** single text that appears in any formula anywhere, which is extremely annoying.

Is there an appropriate/canonical solution to this problem?  In principle, I have never had a problem because I never insert formulas in italicised text (I find it stylistically inappropriate), but I would still like to do it in an appropriate way.

Comment: Then use `\textrm`. I haven't seen many cases where the letter spacing have been bad for `\mathrm` so an example of that would be nice. `\textrm` or `\textnormal` becomes relevant when this text index can have non-acsii letters for example for the radius of a latex, in Danish we might write  `$R_{\textup{sø}}$`, this would wide warnings with `\mathrm` as `ø` is not allowed in math-mode.

Comment: Note According to ISO 80000,  is "standards for weird unconventional use of mathematics for engineering" don't use it as a guide for use of mathmatics in general.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As a physicist, I know that mathematicians are hostile to ISO 80000, but in SCIENCES and engineering we are dealing with a special concepts called quantities and units, so ISO 80000 rules make a lot of sense to us. Do you think mathematicians should dictate to other disciplines how they use mathematics?

Comment: @Pygmalion no the fact that there is an ISO standard for mathematical notation in specifc disciplines is a good thing. What is bad, really shockingly   bad is  iso 8000-2 changing its title from **Mathematical signs and symbols to be used in the natural sciences and technology** (2009) to **Mathematics**  (2019) .

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, I was not aware of the change, as I still use the old ones and do not have funds to get new ones...

Comment: @Pygmalion I have not paid either but the names are confirmed by https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/9282  and https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/29416

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Are there no mathematicians on the ISO committees? Were they unable to came to some mutual agreement with scientists and engineers? Or is it inherently impossible to use the same mathematical notation everywhere?

Comment: iso doesn't try to force global standards, just documents standards globally, so ODF being a word procesor ISO standard doesn't stop Microsoft Office Open XML being an ISO standard as well.  So if an engineering group standardise a notation and publish it that wouldn't trigger a (futile) attempt to gobally standardise mathematical notation, even if they did change the title to give that impression.

Comment: @daleif You can see the extract from the standard in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pdflatex `\mathrm`  uses correct letterspacing and ligatures in the roman font specifed for math (eg as used by `\cos` or `\log`) `\text` uses whatever font is current outside the math so may be a completely different font family, so the problem is not just for italic text.

So `\mathrm` ought to be unequivocally the correct command  to use, except that history is complicated, and for various legacy compatibility reasons even when the text is set in T1 encoding, math roman is set (usually) in the 7 bit OT1 encoding.

So practically speaking if using non-ascii letters I would use `\textrm`, making sure to use `amsmath` so that `\textrm` gets smaller in subscripts.

Comment: Thanks, I will use `amsmath` and `\textrm` from now on.  I wonder how many more inconsistencies are in my huge documents, this one was discovered by pure chance asking completely unrelated question... (facepalm)

Answer (score 1):

Although I accepted David Carlisle's answer, I have second thoughts about his advice. Below you can see the clip from ISO 80000-1:2007.

[image]

In the description, the term *roman* is used as a synonym for *upright*, not for *serif*. Furthermore, in the examples below you can clearly see that the sans serif font from the text is transferred to the subscripts. This actually makes sense, because `gas` in the text should have exactly the same font as `g` in the subscript, apart from the fact that `g` is (always) upright.

My conclusion is that neither `\mathrm` nor `\textrm` nor `\text` is the correct solution, but

- `\textnormal` to return to the default global text font (here I assume that default text is always upright)
- `\textup` (possibly combined with `\textmd` to turn off bold) to return back to the local upright text font